# What is gem to Authenticating with the Meetup?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, meetup

I am looking for the ruby/rails gem that deals with the Authentication API for Meetup.com

http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meetup.com, at this time, does not have an official (or unofficial) ruby gem specific to it, but the API does use the oauth 2.0 protocol  for authorization, so you can use the `oauth2` gem for example, or even `rack-oauth2` if you prefer a middleware solution